# Get user id from email?

Tags: functions, email, id, input

I'm working on an email system, and I'm onto the unsubscribing stage.  Since most of my users would not know their user ID, I'm asking them to put their email into a text box (definitely preferred, since this IS an email system).  In order to change their user meta (their subscribed status), I need to know the users ID.  I mean I suppose I could pass it into an email and put it in the unsubscribe link, but I'm planning on sending out emails to people who don't have wordpress accounts.

So my main question is this:

What logic or functions should I use to determine a users ID from an inputted email address, and if none are found, store them in the wordpress database?

Thanks, I appreciate every answer!!

Comment: Could use generate a random key for each userid and then have an unsubscribe link that contains e-mail and key? If you're doing it by means of a form, pass the e-mail to POST and then lookup/unsubscribe from there?

Comment: I see what you mean.  I could probably add their email and their ID (if they have one), and if not provide a random nonce or random number to verify.  However, in the case that they decide to just go to that page (instead of using the link), I don't want to save an email to the database (of unsubbed users) when it could correlate with a user (and therefore their own user meta).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `user_exists` function. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/email_exists

> This function will check whether or not a given email address ($email) has already been registered to a username, and returns that users ID (or false if none exists).

If the email address does not exist (`user_exists` returns `false`), you may want to use the `wp_create_user` function. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user

> The wp_create_user function allows you to insert a new user into the WordPress database

Only do that if you want to create a WordPress user though, which you may or may not. I'm a bit confused by this part of the question.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you use:  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by

Comment: This and the chosen answer both do what I want.  Thank you for your quick replies!

Answer (score -1):

You can only get this email and verify if there is any user have this email then change this email by the correspond username
like this

```
$login ='anything@me.com';
if(is_email( $login )){
            if( email_exists( $login )) {
              $userID__ = email_exists($login);
              $user_info_kim = get_userdata($userID__);
              $login  = $user_info_kim->user_login;
            }
        }
```